# How to draw multiple graphs by having same axis but changing x-axis forward with R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph

I want to plot two different pairs but with the same x-axis but once the plot is drawn in R, it does not change the x-axis for the next one. For example, I want to have both (x,y) pair and (a,b) pair in the same plot. I write:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
y <- c(5,3,2,10,8,6,1)

a <- c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b <- c(4,5,8,12,2,6,11)

plot(x,y , type= "l")
lines(a,b)
```

and it gives me this pic:

[image]

I want it to draw a plot with x-axis from 1 to 10 and y-axis from 2 to 11. This is a simplified example, and in reality, I want to have around five different density plots in the same plot in which the x-axis do not cover each other in some places. I will be appreciated if you explain that this may change the solution or no. Also, I can't use ggplot2 because the dataset is not a panel with group variable available. It is only several pairs of points.

Comment: You're showing a line plot but refer to "density plots"; usually a density plot refers to a kernel density plot of the form `plot(density(x))` the integral of which equals 1. Can you please clarify? I also don't understand why you *"can't use ggplot2 because the dataset is not a panel with group variable available."* I see no reason why you *shouldn't* be able to use `ggplot`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers after a few estimations I am derivating option prices twice which gives me the implied PDF of options. So these PDFs are just pairs of price-probability in several data-frames. I mean I don't know how to use ggplot2 because they are in different data-frames and there is no group variable. It is appreciated if you can clarify in the above simple example that if its possible to use ggplot2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly advise rethinking the general data structure; it is advisable to store data in e.g. a `list` of `data.frame`s.

For example let's consider the following `list` based on your sample data.

```
lst <- list(
    one = data.frame(x = x, y = y),
    two = data.frame(x = a, y = b))
```

We can then plot data using a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse);
lst %>%
    bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y, group = id)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Or using facets with free `x` scales:

```
lst %>%
    bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y, group = id)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~id, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: This helped a lot, Thank you. @MauritsEvers